# systemd tries to start network before driver initialization is complete

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, centos-7, systemd

I have 2 systems running CentOS 7 with kernel 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64.

Everything is running fine, however, I've tried to upgrade my kernel version to 5.9.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 and now my Ethernet interface does not have its configured IP address on boot. This happens on both machines.

The log says:

```
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Reached target Login Prompts.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started Resets System Activity Logs.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started Login Service.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started Authorization Manager.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started NTP client/server.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started Load CPU microcode update.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: power_meter ACPI000D:00: Found ACPI power meter.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: power_meter ACPI000D:00: hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.0: Multiqueue Enabled: Rx Queue count = 63, Tx Queue count = 63 XDP Queue count = 0
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a network: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.0: 31.504 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth (8.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link)
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.0: MAC: 4, PHY: 0, PBA No: H86377-006
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.0: a0:36:9f:28:8e:6c
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a network: Bringing up interface eth2:  ERROR     : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device eth2 does not seem to be present, delaying initialisation.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth: Device eth2 does not seem to be present, delaying initialisation.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a network: [FAILED]
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a kernel: libphy: ixgbe-mdio: probed
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: network.service failed.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Reached target Network.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Reached target Network is Online.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Starting System Logging Service...
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started Filebeat.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started System Logging Service.
Oct 20 10:11:15 pdb-01a systemd: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: power_meter ACPI000D:00: Found ACPI power meter.
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: power_meter ACPI000D:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap!
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.1: Multiqueue Enabled: Rx Queue count = 63, Tx Queue count = 63 XDP Queue count = 0
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.1: 31.504 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth (8.0 GT/s PCIe x4 link)
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.1: MAC: 4, PHY: 0, PBA No: H86377-006
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.1: a0:36:9f:28:8e:6e
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: ixgbe 0000:d8:00.1: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
Oct 20 10:11:16 pdb-01a kernel: libphy: ixgbe-mdio: probed
Oct 20 10:11:17 pdb-01a systemd: Started Dynamic System Tuning Daemon.
Oct 20 10:11:17 pdb-01a systemd: Reached target Multi-User System.
Oct 20 10:11:17 pdb-01a systemd: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Oct 20 10:11:17 pdb-01a systemd: Started Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection 10s After Completed Startup.
Oct 20 10:11:17 pdb-01a systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Oct 20 10:11:47 pdb-01a systemd: Starting Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection...
```

It looks like systemd tries to start the network before the driver initialization is complete.

After the system boots, `ifup eth2` works perfectly. Is there any way to make systemd wait for the driver to be ready?

All the best,

RfTf

Comment: I have just tested it with kernel version 4.4.218 - exactly the same problem.

It seems I can only get it to work with the kernel version that was bundled with CentOS 7: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64